# How can I move the field state in the header in odoo'

Tags: xml, odoo

How can I move the field state from the top of the invoice form?
I searched the field but i don't founded, I want to move the field to the left, as you can see in the next image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to add status on the left side. Status bar implemented in Odoo core. So it may affect the other form view.

I would suggest keeping it as it is if you have only one status.

Generally, the status bar has more names so it displays either according to the given order in the xml view or in the (py) field declaration.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It is better to use Odoo's core as is. You can solve this by training the users to look for the text where it is currently located.

Answer (score 0):

Only one way to do that and that is adding backend CSS to that status bar.
This below code help you to do that

```
.o_form_view .o_form_statusbar {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.o_form_view .o_form_statusbar > .o_statusbar_status {
    margin-left: **set margin as per your need**;    
}
```